# Josephar problem procedure based solution

Tags: c++

recently i found a procedure based solution for Josephar problem. I don't get the way they remove the child from the ring.
Can someone explain the line i marked, thx

```
struct Jose{
int code; //child number
Jose* next; // point to next child
};
//-----------------------------------
int n=10,s=3,m=3 //number of children, intial position, counting gap
Jose* pCur, *pivot;
//-----------------------------------
Jose* createRing(){
    Jose* px = new Jose[n];
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        px[i-1].next = &px[i%n]; // loop back
        px[i-1].code = i;
    }//-----------------------------------
    cout << "There are " <<n<<" boys.\n";
    pivot = &px[n-2];
    pCur = &px[n-1];
    countBoy(s-1); // start from beginning
    return px;
}
//-----------------------------------
void countBoy(int m){
    for(int i = 0; i<m; ++i){
        pivot = pCur;
        pCur = pCur->next;
    }
}//-----------------------------------
void process(){
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
        countBoy(m);
        static int line = 0;
        cout <<"leaving "<<pCur->code<< endl;
        if(!(++line%10)) cout <<"\n";

//==========================================
//==========================================
//==========================================
//==========================================
//==========================================

//EXPLAIN THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES
        pivot->next = pCur->next;  //get rid of current child
        pCur = pivot;
    } 
}
```

Why would the highlighted line remove the current child from the list?
What happened to the list after these two lines?

Comment: All it does is assigns the node to another node. So basically you move a node forward then you make another assignment? which effectively drops the node.

Comment: wait, im confused. Why would moving a node forward then making an assignment drop the node? Can you explain a bit more about it

Comment: The node that you move past gets detached from the linked list. here is an image that is okay for [illustration](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~skrentny/cs367-common/readings/Linked-Lists/removeFirst.gif).